# method not found exception but method does exist and is implemented

Tags: java, cdi, weld

I have an issue with the following.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError :ResourcePreviewRepository.objectExists(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
```

During runtime and debugging, this is the class.

```
EntityRepository$GenericRepository$ResourcePreviewRepository$1323269030$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.objectExists(Unknown Source)
```

This is the definition of the ResourcePreviewRepository

```
public interface ResourcePreviewRepository extends GenericRepository<String>, EntityRepository<String, ResourceMetadata>
```

Now: the objectExists method DOES exist in the concrete implementation of GenericRepository called AbstractJcrRepository. But also this method is defined in the EntityRepository interface (I expect here lies the problem).

```
public interface GenericRepository<IdentifierType extends Serializable> {
   boolean objectExists(IdentifierType id) throws RepositoryException;
}


public class AbstractJcrRepository implements GenericRepository<String> {

   @Override
   public boolean objectExists(final String id) throws RepositoryException {
      ...
   }

}
```

Note that when I add a cast to GenericRepository, it does work, but obviously I do not want to cast.

This is the final impl I am supposed to be getting:

```
public class JcrResourcePreviewRepositoryImpl extends AbstractJcrEntityRepository<ResourceMetadata> implements ResourcePreviewRepository
```

But although I do have the implementation AND the method available I get this Error. How can I fix this?

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE WITH SOLUTION**
I won't post this is an answer but I had to add the missing method to the interface. Although the impl class which is returned by the Producer surely does implement this method, but only through inheritance of an interface plus it's extension. So declaring this method twice in the inheritance chain solved it.

Comment: More code would be helpful.

Comment: I don't see any reason to assume that method exists in the interface.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]

Comment: put your code with method implementaion also

Comment: I added more code

Answer (score 0):

As `AbstractJcrRepository` does'nt implements `ResourcePreviewRepository`, it's not this implementation which is used when the exception occured.

Comment: that doesn't make sense right?, because the ResourcePreviewRepository inherits the methods from the extension. Also it does compile fine. The final implementation should contain the method impl.

Comment: ResourcePreviewRepository is an interface so it doesn't take the implementation of his extention. The implementation of ResourcePreviewRepository has to extends AbstractJcrRepository to get it.

Comment: it does do that, I will add more code, maybe that was unclear

Comment: Are the signatures identical in both interfaces (with throws)? `GenericRepository` && `EntityRepository`

Comment: Maybe because `boolean objectExists(final String id)` not equals to `boolean objectExists(IdentifierType id)`.  `String` does not extends `IdentifierType`.  But I think you should get an error at compile time.

Comment: no this is a generic, the Identifier is replaced by <String>

Comment: Your method is not generic and request a IdentifierType

Comment: no. at runtine the Identifier is a String, interface GenericRepository<IdentifierType extends Serializable> and implements GenericRepository<String>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122917/discussion-between-phox-and-coen-damen).